# MediaWiki, formatting the search result without search engines?

Tags: search, formatting, mediawiki, markup

My company use a hosted web server, so I can´t install custom search engines based on java like [Lucene-search](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lucene-search). Are there another way to display the search results without markup?

Comment: What do you mean with "without markup"? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a zillion hosted elasticsearch providers; it doesn't have to be installed on the same server than MediaWiki.